# ModuleNotFound error - tensorflow on Anaconda Navigator 1.9.6 in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, anaconda

```
import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I was importing keras in my deep learning project, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are using Python 3.7.

To install keras with tensorflow you have to setup a Python 3.6 environment in Anaconda. keras with tensorflow does not work in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

These might be the errors,

1. You not have the installed the Microsoft Redist C++ 2015 Update 3. It contains msvcp.dll which in most cases is lost for Tensorflow. Try installing it.
2. Your CPU does not support AVX instructions. TensorFlow from v1.6 requires AvX supported processors.
3. Try installing version 1.10.0. It works well in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create an environment for tensorflow project with all the tools I need: e.g. Go to your Start and find Anaconda Prompt:

In it, do

```
conda create --name deep python=3.6 tensorflow
```

This will create an environment called deep with Python 3.6 and tensorflow. To go in:

```
conda activate deep
```

While in this environment, you have both tensorflow running on Python 3.6. You can install other packages as

```
conda install -n deep keras scikitlearn pandas
```

This code can be done in any environment and yet install those packages to your deep package